# xpath expression for node with attribute value equals to variable value

Tags: c#, xpath, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have problem where i need to find node with Name =  Value
and Value is a c# string.

String Value ="XYZ" and Value gets assigned dynamically.

```
<ReportParameters>    
<ReportParameter Name="XYZ">
  <DefaultValue>
    <DataSetReference>
      <DataSetName>P_GetValues</DataSetName>
      <ValueField>ID</ValueField>
    </DataSetReference>
  </DefaultValue>
</ReportParameter>
<ReportParameter Name="ABC">
  <DefaultValue>
    <DataSetReference>
      <DataSetName>PL</DataSetName>
      <ValueField>sdf</ValueField>
    </DataSetReference>
  </DefaultValue>
</ReportParameter>
</ReportParameters>`
```

How to write Xpath expression for this or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
// the text to search
string txt = "XYZ";

// loading my xml in an XElement
var el = XElement.Load("test.xml");

// executing the xpath query   
var result = el.XPathSelectElement("//ReportParameter[@Name = '" + txt + "']");
```